# Web Scraping Amazon "See More Buying Options" Node Cheerio Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I am trying to web scrape amazon for GPU prices (How original!).  I am an elementary school teacher trying a fun beginner node project to get prices on amazon.

There are three options I have found when scraping... Available Add to cart, See other buying options, and currently unavailable.

I have been able to see if the "add to cart" button is present by checking the length and can scrape the price to see if it's one I'd be willing to pay, then alert me. However, when checking other buying options, I can get to the side pane but I can't scrape the prices of the other buying options because cheerio cannot see a specific ID.  Each "buying option" div has an ID="#aod-offer", but even when seeing if it is present, it returns 0, even though I clearly see it in the inspector.  I have been practicing on pages that have at least 1 buying option.  Not sure why it is not scraping any data.

I have been practicing on this card:
[https://www.amazon.com/Gaming-GeForce-Graphics-DisplayPort-Bearings/dp/B08TFLDLTM/ref=sr_1_17?crid=1FL7W42YBL5XB&dchild=1&keywords=geforce+rtx+3080+graphics+card&qid=1617721759&s=electronics&sprefix=GeForce+rtx+3080+graphics+card%2Celectronics%2C173&sr=1-17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TFLDLTM)

```
//Scrapes amazon pages
async function CheckAvailability(page){

//for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){}
await page.goto(items[1].url);
const html = await page.content();
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    
//If add to cart button is present
if($("#add-to-cart-button").length > 0){
    
    //Check price of item
    const priceStr = $("#price_inside_buybox").text().replace("$", "");
    const price = Number(priceStr);
    console.log(priceStr);
    console.log(price);

    //Check price against what you are willing to spend
     if(checkPrice(price)){
        console.log("You are willing to buy this item");
     }else{
        console.log("The price is too rich for your blood!");
     }

// Check if there are other sellers
}else if ($("#unqualifiedBuyBox").length > 0){
    console.log("There might be others");
    await page.$eval("a[title ='See All Buying Options']", elem => elem.click());
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    
    const offers = [];
    const offerListings = $("#aod-offer").each((i, e) => {
        offers[i] = $(e).html();
    });
    console.log(offers);
       

// Currently unavailable is displayed
}else if ($("#outOfStock").length > 0){
    console.log("There are none available, moving on...");
}
}

//Checks a price against what I'm willing to spend.  Lowered the number for testing.  I know I cannot 
get a gpu for $200
function checkPrice(price){
if (price < 200){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my code is probably pretty basic, but I changed my const $ to Let $ and reloaded cheerio with new HTML data in the else if section, and it worked.  I thought because I was on the same page that my cheerio did not have to be updated but apparently it did.